# Python Pandas groupby using values in another dataframe without for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, pandas-groupby

I have a code that is working, but which is slow.
I have one dataframe with data 'djk' that I want to sum up based on a complex groupby function.
I need to group them by 'COUNTERPARTY', 'CURRENCY' and 'Maturity_Bucket'. Both 'djk' and 'Maturity_Bucket' are dataframes with many rows and columns (same size). I want the groupby function to use the corresponding column when grouping. I have solved the problem with a for-loop, but it is slow for large dataframes. Is there another way, to write this code faster, removing the for-loop?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 10000
m = 200
n_name = 25
data_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 4, size=(n, m))).astype(int)
data_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(n, m)))
data_1['COUNTERPARTY'] = (np.random.randint(10, n_name, n)).astype(str)
data_1['COUNTERPARTY'] = 'COUNTERPARTY_' + data_1['COUNTERPARTY']
data_1['CURRENCY'] = (np.random.randint(0, 3, n)).astype(str)
data_1['CURRENCY'] = 'CURRENCY_' + data_1['CURRENCY']


result_pd = pd.DataFrame(0, index=data_1['COUNTERPARTY'].unique(), columns=range(m))


def f_2_support(srs):
    cnt = {k: v for k, v in zip(srs.index.get_level_values(2), srs)}
    a = cnt.get(1, 0)
    b = cnt.get(2, 0)
    c = cnt.get(3, 0)
    return np.sqrt(a ** 2 + b ** 2 + c ** 2 + 1.4 * a * b + 1.4 * b * c + 0.6 * a * c)


for i in range(m):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['COUNTERPARTY'] = data_1['COUNTERPARTY']
    df['CURRENCY'] = data_1['CURRENCY']
    df['djk'] = data_2.loc[:, i]
    df['Maturity_Bucket'] = data_1.loc[:, i]
    result_pd.loc[:, i] = df.groupby(['COUNTERPARTY', 'CURRENCY', 'Maturity_Bucket']).agg({'djk': 'sum'}).groupby(
            ['COUNTERPARTY', 'CURRENCY']).agg({'djk': lambda x: f_2_support(x)}).groupby('COUNTERPARTY').agg(
            {'djk': 'sum'})
```

I am trying the code below, without success. It returns an empty Series only.
What is wrong?

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({i: f_2_new_column(data_2 , data_1, i) for i in range(m)})

def f_2_new_column(data_2 , data_1, n):
    return data_2 .iloc[:, n].groupby([data_1['COUNTERPARTY'], data_1['CURRENCY'], data_1.iloc[:, n]]).agg('sum').groupby(
            [data_1['COUNTERPARTY'], data_1['CURRENCY']]).agg(lambda x: f_2_support(x)).groupby(data_1['COUNTERPARTY']).agg(
            'sum')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['COUNTERPARTY'] = data_1['COUNTERPARTY']
df['CURRENCY'] = data_1['CURRENCY']
df['Maturity_Bucket'] = data_1.loc[:, 1]

for i in range(m):
df['djk'] = data_2.loc[:, i]
result_pd.loc[:, i] = df.groupby(['COUNTERPARTY', 'CURRENCY', 'Maturity_Bucket']).agg({'djk': 'sum'}).groupby(
        ['COUNTERPARTY', 'CURRENCY']).agg({'djk': lambda x: f_2_support(x)}).groupby('COUNTERPARTY').agg(
        {'djk': 'sum'})
```

Same code just a little bit modified. Every time you ran the for loop you were creating a dataframe, and slicing the columns again and again

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the original posting.
The problem I face is that I want to groupby on df['Maturity_Bucket'] = data_1.loc[:, i], so a new column in every loop.

Comment: Maybe you can try adding df['Maturity_Bucket'] = data_1.loc[:, i] inside the for loop and put everything else outside.

Comment: Yes, that is what I have done in my code actually myself. What I wonder is if there is a way to write the code without the for-loop. Maybe an apply with lambda or something that makes the code considerably faster.